# How to calculate the average of each row and column in array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix

So yesterday I asked for help, and a lot of people helped me out with my question, I really appreciated that guys. However, I run into a second problem of my homework, and I have been trying to solve it from this morning, and now it's like almost 2AM in the morning, and I'm not gonna sleep until I solve this problem. I'm not going to lie, so this is my homework to test the basic knowledge of mine. I know I make major mistakes somewhere, so please help me to point them out, so I can fix them. Thank you

The output should be:

```
  1, 2, 3, ave=2
  4, 5, 6, ave=5
aver=2.5, 3.5, 4.5
```

This is my current code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number for rows: ");
        int rows = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter a number for columns: ");
        int columns = input.nextInt();

        int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

        System.out.println("Enter the numbers in array: ");

        for(int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j<columns ; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for(int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0  ; j<columns ; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " , ");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");    
        }  
    }
    double averageRow(int[][] array) {
        int rowTotal = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for (int rows = 0; rows < array.length; rows++) {
            for (int columns = 0; columns < array[rows].length; columns++) {
                rowTotal += array[rows][columns];
            }
            average = rowTotal / array[rows].length;
            System.out.println(average);
            rowTotal = 0;
        }
        return rowTotal;    
    }
    double averageColumn(int[][] array) {
        int columnTotal = 0;
        double average = 0;

        for (int columns = 0; columns < array.length; columns++) {
            for (int rows = 0; rows < array[columns].length; rows++) {
                columnTotal += array[rows][columns];
            }
            average = columnTotal / array[columns].length;
            System.out.println(average);
            columnTotal = 0;
        }
        return columnTotal;  
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly seems to be a problem?

Comment: 1. Always write what you need to. You don't need to tell us the whole story. Just problem and code is much appreciable. **No thankyou, No I will appreciate etc needed.**         2. If you find any answer good or best, please accept it.

Comment: A first problem would be `columnTotal = 0;` before returning it and the same for the `rowTotal`.

Comment: So I am trying to cal. the average of each row and column in my matrix and print them out, but I got stuck at writing the codes to cal. the average of rows and columns. Since the size of the matrix is depended on the number of rows and columns that users will put in.

Comment: You could return void and just print the results, or return arrays where each element is the average for a specific row/column. As for the call it should be `averageRow(array)` where `array = new int[rows][columns]`

Comment: You should be looping using the row and column sizes you already have as input from the user; why going for array.length.

Comment: You wrote 2 functions for calculating the averages of row elements and coloumn elements.But you didn't use functions yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of rows");
    int r = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of columns");
    int c = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter values");
    int[][] matrix = new int[r][c];

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        float rowSum = 0f;
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            rowSum += matrix[i][j];
        }
        System.out.println("Average of row " + i + " " + rowSum / c);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        float columnSum = 0f;
        for (int j = 0; j < r; j++)
        {
            columnSum += matrix[j][i];
        }
        System.out.println("Average of column " + i + " " + columnSum / r);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```

You can find the each row sum while reading the data. For column average run loop again. Hope you will sleep :)

Answer (score 0):

You can print without calling other function.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test8 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number for rows: ");
        int rows = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter a number for columns: ");
        int columns = input.nextInt();

        int[][] array = new int[rows][columns];

        System.out.println("Enter the numbers in array: ");

        for(int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0 ; j<columns ; j++)
            {
                array[i][j] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        int rowSum = 0;
        int colSumArr[] = new int[columns];
        for(int i=0 ; i<rows ; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0  ; j<columns ; j++)
            {
                rowSum = rowSum + array[i][j];
                colSumArr[j] = colSumArr[j] + array[i][j];
                System.out.print(array[i][j] + " , ");
            }
            System.out.println( " ave=" + (double)rowSum/columns);
            rowSum = 0;
        }
        System.out.printf("aver=");
        for(int i=0;i<columns;i++){
            if(i!=columns -1)
                System.out.print((double)colSumArr[i]/rows + ", ");
            else
                System.out.print((double)colSumArr[i]/rows);
        }
    }

}
```